# Oracle query time on date fields

Tags: sql, oracle, select, time

I have a column of type DATE stored data are contains date and time . I can see value when i do

```
select   CAST(MSG_DT AS TIMESTAMP) from   table;
```

this is the output

```
17-MAR-08 15:38:59,000000000
```

I have to select the row using

- Only date

  ```
  select       CAST(MSG_DT AS TIMESTAMP) from   
  MWRB_RECEIVE where  
  MSG_DT >= TO_DATE( '2000-02-03' ,'YYYY-MM-DD')  
  and  
  MSG_DT <= TO_DATE( '2010-02-03' ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  ```
- Only time (eg: every message between 12:00:11 and 23:02:55)

---

In DB2 i can do

```
SELECT *                          
FROM TABLE              
WHERE DATE(INS_TMS) = '2014-02-18'

SELECT *                          
FROM TABLE              
WHERE TIME(INS_TMS) > '09.55.00'
```

In ORACLE I can't see the equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM your_table
 WHERE TO_CHAR (start_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '2014-10-06'
       AND TO_CHAR (start_date, 'hh24:mi:ss') > '10:00:00'
```

Comment: OK but you write this because you are sure that there are no TIME function or because it's more simply use the char. As I told to Raad the nearest one is EXTRACT but i have to work with strings. It's error prone.

Comment: to_Char is the way i know to do this. If exist a time function that can do this, much better, but until now i haven't see it.

Comment: OK i use your method without :

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting the column value to a TIMESTAMP when the column in the database is a DATE type?  The fractional part of the seconds will always be 0, as DATE only has resolution to the seconds value.  You need to add the hours,minutes, and seconds format specifier to the query:

```
select MSG_DT from
MWRB_RECEIVE 
where MSG_DT between TO_DATE( '2000-02-03 12:00:11' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND
           TO_DATE( '2010-02-03 23:02:55' ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: This is nice when I have an initial date and an end date. In my case the second question don't use any date because I have no start date or end date

Comment: I use the cast only for visualization purpouse.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to split date and hour, you can have it in a single where clause

where field > to_date('20121212 12:12:12, 'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS')

Check for your reference oracle to_date() as it seems the only thing you need

Comment: Sorry my question is "Only time (eg: every message between 12:00:11 and 23:02:55)" i'm not interested in DATE every day is OK. I have no  DATE interval only time interval.